# How to draw a dynamic line chart based on an infotable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I want to draw a **dynamic** line chart based on an infotable using d3.js. I have converted the information in the infotable into two arrays: a **one-dimensional** array `xValueArray: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40]` and a **two-dimensional** array `yValueArray: [[0, 20, 30, 40, 50], [0, 200, 250, 400, 450]]`. My logic is so that I can get a dataset with the xValueArray mapped to both arrays in yValueArray to represent x and y-coordinates. Therefore, I have used the map function to make the dataset.

```
    var result = xValueArray.map(function (x, i) { 
        return [x, yValueArray[0][i]];
    });
    console.log(result); //returns [[0,0], [10,20], [20,30], [30,40], [40, 50]]

    var data = result.map(function(d) {
        return {
          x: d[0],
          y: d[1]
        };
    });
    console.log(data); //returns [[x:0, y:0], [x:10, y:20], [x:20, y:30], [x:30, y:40], [x:40, y:50]]

    //************* Plotting of graph ***************   
    var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) {return y(d.y); })
        .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    //plot line
    var path1 = g.append("path")
        .attr("class", "path1")
        .attr("id", "blueLine")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

The line chart will be plotted just fine, with the only **one** line plotted as I only mapped the first array in yValueArray to xValueArray. However, I want to make the chart **dynamic**, meaning that I want the line chart to be plotted according to the number of data fields which my user's input in the infotable. In this case, the number of data fields is 2 since there are 2 arrays in yValueArray. If the number of data fields increases, the number of arrays in yValueArray increases as well and I have to plot the corresponding line on the line chart.

How should I go about doing this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using your `x` array as a base for mapping the `y` values, do it the other way around:

```js
const yValueArray = [
  [0, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  [0, 200, 250, 400, 450]
];

const xValueArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40];

const data = yValueArray.map(data =>
  data.map((d, i) => ({
    x: xValueArray[i],
    y: d
  }))
);

console.log(data);
```

This will work for how many inner arrays you have on `yValueArray`.

Then use that data in your enter selection:

```js
const yValueArray = [
  [0, 20, 30, 40, 50],
  [0, 200, 250, 400, 450]
];

const xValueArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40];

const data = yValueArray.map(data =>
  data.map((d, i) => ({
    x: xValueArray[i],
    y: d
  }))
);

const x = d3.scaleLinear();
const y = d3.scaleLinear();

const lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveLinear);

const path1 = d3.select("svg").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction)
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="400"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually thought about that but didn't know how to implement it using the right syntax. However, you seem to have missed my point about the line chart needing to be dynamic. I now have 10 points in the dataset, but 5 of the points are for one line while the other 5 are for another line as they represent different datafields. Therefore, two lines should be plotted instead of all 10 points on one line. Do I have to split the data array into the number of datafields? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Yes, you have to. But that's a different question, therefore please post it as a new question, with the relevant details. By the way you don't need the D3 tag for that one, since it's just a JS problem.